# target db size doubles on coalesce

Tags: java, sqlite, jooq

1.db is becoming double in size compared to input size each time coalesce is called with concat. After inserting 20 MB data, 1.db becomes 30MB of size.

Input : Lines has now 10MB of data

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
char[] buffer = new char[10 * 1000 * 1000];    
StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();    
lines.append(String.valueOf(buffer, 0, reader.read(buffer)));
```

Round 1 insert -

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:target/1.db");
Settings settings = new Settings();
settings.setExecuteLogging(false);
File reader2 = new File("target/1.db");

try (DSLContext dsl = DSL.using(connection,settings)) {

    dsl.createTable("TABLE1")
            .column("COL1", SQLiteDataType.CLOB)
            .column("COL2", SQLiteDataType.CLOB)
            .execute();


    dsl.insertInto(TABLE1)
            .columns(TABLE1.COL1, TABLE1.COL2)
            .values("ABB", null)
            .execute();

    Field<String> coalesce = DSL.coalesce(TABLE1.COL2, "");
    dsl.update(TABLE1).set(TABLE1.COL2, DSL.concat(coalesce, DSL.val(lines.toString())))
            .where(TABLE1.COL1.eq("ABB"))
            .execute();

    Result<Record2<String, String>> result = dsl.select(TABLE1.COL1, TABLE1.COL2)
            .from(TABLE1)
            .where(TABLE1.COL1.eq("ABB"))
            .fetch();

    System.out.println("input length: " + lines.length());
    System.out.println("File size:" + reader2.length());
    if (result.getValue(0, TABLE1.COL2) != null) {
        System.out.println("Col1 length: " + result.getValue(0, TABLE1.COL1).length());
        System.out.println("Col2 length: " + result.getValue(0, TABLE1.COL2).length());
    }
```

Output :

```
input length: 10000000 //10 mb payload
File size:10113024  // file size increased by 10 MB
Col1 length: 3
Col2 length:10000000 // col2 length
```

Inserting 10MB more however inflates file size to 30MB with "coalesce" and "concat". Unable to figure out where extra 10 MB is being added here.

Round 2 insert -

```
dsl.update(TABLE1).set(TABLE1.COL2, DSL.concat(coalesce, DSL.val(lines.toString())))
    .where(TABLE1.COL1.eq("ABB"))
    .execute();


result = dsl.select(TABLE1.COL1, TABLE1.COL2)
    .from(TABLE1)
    .where(TABLE1.COL1.eq("ABB"))
    .fetch();

System.out.println("input length: " + lines.length());
System.out.println("File size:" + reader2.length());
if (result.getValue(0, TABLE1.COL2) != null) {
    System.out.println("Col1 length: " + result.getValue(0, TABLE1.COL1).length());
    System.out.println("Col2 length: " + result.getValue(0, TABLE1.COL2).length());
}
```

Output:

```
input length: 10000000 //input size
File size:30322688  // increased from 10MB to 30MB for additional 10MB input 
Col1 length: 3
Col2 length:20000000 //col 2 length
```

Does it have to do with Unicode encoding ?

Comment: In many RDBMS, an update statement will not really modify the existing record, but create a new record, copy all its contents (along with the updated content) and mark the old record as deleted. This is an important feature to have when you want to be able to undo your changes through rollback.

Comment: Also, here's an interesting article on SQLite and transactions: https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-971aff98eef2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to know about 1 sqlite workaroud -

```
dsl.execute("VACUUM; ");
```

Having above run after inserts and updates deflates file back to 20MB.
Can we enable auto vacuum for sqlite using jooq ?

**EDIT**  - Using transaction and VACUUM

```
try (DSLContext dsl = DSL.using(dbUrl)) {
    dsl.transaction((ctx) -> {
        dsl.createTable("TABLE1")
            .column("COL1", SQLiteDataType.CLOB)
            .column("COL2", SQLiteDataType.CLOB)
            .execute();

        dsl.insertInto(TABLE1)
            .columns(TABLE1.COL1, TABLE1.COL2)
            .values("ABB", null)
            .execute();

        Field<String> coalesce = DSL.coalesce(TABLE1.COL2, "");
        dsl.update(TABLE1).set(TABLE1.COL2, DSL.concat(coalesce, DSL.val(lines.toString())))
            .where(TABLE1.COL1.eq("ABB"))
            .execute();         

    });
    dsl.execute("VACUUM; ");
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't run this statement everywhere, it has its own costs. Just run it right after your loop, or from within your loop.